# Signature the JSON data from client-side to server-side

Tags: javascript

I send some JSON data from client-side to server-side.

The able user can modify the JSON data, because the code is available for anyone (JS script).

How can I check right JSON data against fake JSON data.

I thought about some signature, but I don't any idea how to do it.

Thanks for any help!

Example:

```
//real//
let user = {
    name: "John",
    gender: "man"
}

//fake//
let user = {
    name: "John",
    gender: "woman"
}
```

It is just example, the JSON data can be different.

> EDIT1: I can verify if the data correct or not, but it would be so
>   hard.

Comment: You need to **authenticate** AND **validate** data arriving from the frontend.

Comment: well, you can't. Everything you do on the client side to encode data can be manipulated

Comment: `I can verify if the data correct or not, but it would be so hard.` well, that's what you have to do though. There's no magical shortcut.

Comment: It is a little bit stupid, but can I basic signature the data a on the server check if the signature is correct and check if the code was not modified? Or check the progress of the code?

Comment: If you're sending the data from the server to the client, why do you need the client to send it back? Just keep the data in a session variable on the server. Then you don't need to validate anything.

Comment: But yes, you can sign the data using a private key on the server, then check the signature when the client sends it back.

Comment: @Barmar I don't write anything about sending the data from the server to the client. And yeah, I can sign the data, but I can sign the fake data too. The user decides if the data is fake or not (it means, if the data is modified or not).

Comment: You wrote **can I basic signature the data a on the server**. If you don't send it from the server to the client, how will the client get the signature so it can send it back for verification?

Comment: The user can't sign fake data because they don't know the server's private key.

Comment: If is the private key recieved in front-end code, the user knows the private key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the a JSONSchema validator for Javascript. @TDEGrunt has a nice one [here](https://github.com/tdegrunt/jsonschema). For examples on how to use it, see the readme file.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like it's potentially making a mountain out of a molehill.

It sounds like by "fake" data you mean data the user should not be allowed to amend, and/or which isn't entirely logical? Instead of trying to control what they send, which is very difficult, you just simply check it instead. You should:

a) validate what they send (this should be done anyway, to check for things like strings where there should be numbers, or value combinations which logically don't belong together (e.g. `"state: "Alaska", "country: "Russia"`)) and return a validation error when it finds a problem,

and/or

b) have your server ignore any fields which the user should not be updating (this is a defence against what's sometimes called an "over-posting" attack).

and/or

c) check the user's permissions to the specific item of data. e.g. perhaps they are permitted to amend their own name, but not someone else's.

Validation of data can be tedious, yes, but it's a normal and very necessary part of any web-based application. Since you are not in full control of the client, you therefore cannot trust any information you are sent, and you must always check that the data is basically valid, and that the client can verify (against your authentication and authorisation rules) that they have permission to send that data (or indeed, to be given data, if that's the purpose of the request).

Most programming frameworks have features built in (and often enhanced by 3rs party packages to make validation, authentication and authorisation much less painful to code.